# how can I catch a non-fatal error in processing

Tags: processing

i have this piece of code im trying to run:

```
float curX;
curX = map(millis(), timeStart, timeEnd, fromX, toX);
// the code itself works fine so variables and stuff aren't really important
```

and because of the circumstances of the program, sometimes it will give errors like this: `map(992, 1000, 1000, 50, 50) called, which returns NaN (not a number)`

this doesn't stop the program but i wanted to know if there was a way to detect if this will happen and such, not run this code so it doesn't fill up the console. maybe using a `try {} catch() {}` statement or something?

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to not fill the console you can add a `if(millis() != timeStart && fromX != toX)` before `curX = ...`